# Approximating arbitrary probability measures by discrete ones

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $\mu$ be an arbitrary probability measure on $H$. I would like to approximate this distribution by by a finitely supported discrete distribution is the following sense:

For every $\varepsilon>0$ I would like to have a finitely supported probability measure $\nu_{\varepsilon}$ so that for every open ball $B$ of diameter $1$ we have
$$|\mu(B)-\nu(B)|<\varepsilon.$$

Is such a statement true? Is it true at least in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: The question has been changed due to a comment by Brendan Mckay's example that refuted the stronger version of the question.

Comment: Take $\mu$ to be the normal distribution on the real line and $\nu$ to be supported on a finite set $X$.  The complement $A$ of $X$ is open yet $\mu(A)=1$ and $\nu(A)=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I will mend the question as I need a weaker statement, but hoped that something stronger could be true, but it turned out to be naive.

Comment: (For second version) Partition $\mathbb{R}^d$ into cubes of side $d^{-1/2}$.   Choose cubes in decreasing order of $\mu$ measure until their total measure exceeds $1-\varepsilon$. That only takes a finite number of choices, since the sequence converges. Now support your discrete measure on the centres of the selected cubes.

Comment: Maybe smaller cubes are needed so that balls centred nearby will cover them.  Hopefully you can work out the details.

Comment: Thank you for your answers - it is most useful!

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure that what I wrote is true.  Have you checked if it works?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I could not make it work, but found a roundabout that was enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This is much too ambitious—it won‘t even work in $[0,1]$ but it is true if in any completely regular space if you replace „open“ by „compact“. This is under the assumption that you are talking about tight measures.  So it will work for $\sigma$-additive measures in your situation, since these are tight when the underlying space is polish as are separable Hilbert spaces.